# Specific Sorted Array Search

Tags: arrays

You are given one sorted array, for example:

```
1 2 3 5 7 9 10 12 13 15 17
```

Then, it is split at one (random) part into two arrays, for example:

```
1 2 3 5 7 9
10 12 13 15 17
```

Then, it is merged together again, but like this:

```
10 12 13 15 17 1 2 3 5 7 9
```

It is asked to write a function which searches through the new array for a specific element and returns its position:

```
int find(int* newArray, int arrayLength, int elementToFind);
```

It is asked to do it as optimal as possible.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? Please post your work.

Comment: Do you know how long each of the 2 arrays was?  If so, you would only need to search in one portion of the final array, based on whether the value you're searching for is greater than or less than the first value in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is based on binary search. Each time a half is picked, algorithm checks whether `half` is bigger than `begin`.

- If it is the case, all items between `begin` and `half` have to be sorted. Algorithm checks whether the needed item is in range `*begin`-`*half`

  - if so another search is conducted in that place (there is a possibility to use normal binary search in such case)
  - otherwise search have to be conducted between `half` and `end`
- if `half` is lover than `begin` there have to be a "slope" in that range, thus

  - if item is outside range `*begin` and `*half` algorithm should search between `begin` and `half`
  - if item is inside range `*begin` and `*half` algorithm should search between `half` and `end`

    ```
    int* find2(int* begin, int* end, int elementToFind)
    {
        int* half = begin + (end-begin + 1)/2;

        if(*begin == elementToFind)
        {
            return begin;
        }

        if(*half > *begin)
        {
            if(*half > elementToFind && *begin < elementToFind)
            {
                return find2(begin, half, elementToFind);
            }
            else
            {
                return find2(half, end, elementToFind);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(*half <= elementToFind && *begin > elementToFind)
            {
                return find2(half, end, elementToFind);
            }
            else
            {
                return find2(begin, half, elementToFind);
            }
        }
    }

    int find(int* newArray, int arrayLength, int elementToFind)
    {
        return find2(newArray, newArray+arrayLength-1, elementToFind) - newArray;
    }
    ```